# How to prevent performing the same segue twice?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I've got a problem with navigation in my iOS app. I have sliding menu with table view of menu items. Tapping on one of those item fires segue which pushes new view controller on the stack. The problem is that I can push the same view controller twice on the same stack. If I select menu item "A" then corresponding view controller is pushed on navigation stack. From this newly pushed view controller I also have an option to select the same "A" menu item and push new istance of the same class as topmost view controller. How can I prevent that?

Not working solutions:
Checking the class of the top controller of navigation stack. But the problem is that I only knows the segue's identifier (NSString* object) and cannot get the information about the destination view controller class. The only place where I can check that class is method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

but I cannot prevent performing the segue from this method.

I have tried saving last performed segue in property but it won't work because when I push "A" view controller, then "B" view controller, then press back button I won't be able to push B again which is wrong :)

Comment: I have Managed something like that by checking the array of ViewControllers in the stack. `self.navigationController.viewControllers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need the following method

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
```

just return false to cancel the segue. You will have something like this(pseudocode):

```
if ([performedSeguesArray contain:identifier])
{
     return NO;
}
else
{
    [performedSeguesArray addObject:identifier];
}

return YES;
```

Comment: Yes, I know this method. But what logic inside. As I wrote in question i cannot get the class for the segue's destination view controller that is about to perfrom.

Comment: you can create parent class for all of your view controllers where you will save all performed segue identifiers. And than you should check if the active segue is in the performed list then it should be canceled

Comment: But "shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier" method will not call often so we have to add some condition.
     `if ([self 
   shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:@"" 
   sender:nil]) {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"" sender:self];
       
 }`

Comment: what do you mean, shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier will called every time when you use segue

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.It is resolved now. Please let me know if this helps.

I already have a segue linked from table view cell to another view with name DynamicSuperView

```
func tableView(_tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
//Remove the below line from this function as it will perform segue.
//performSegue(withIdentifier: "DynamicSegue", sender: self)
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)         {
// This will actually perform your segue
var DestViewController = segue.destination as! DynamicSuperView 
let selectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
DestViewController.labelText = names[selectedRow!]
}
```